# Is there a way to store the value of the current cell and restore it back in Google-sheets?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a script that runs inside a cell that makes an API call and returns a value.

I would like to update the value via the API or decide to keep the original that was returned before. Is that possible?

I thought of caching the value on the adjacent cell, as a cache (backup) and retrieve it from there but things are getting quite complicated when it comes to storing values through setValue() and querying cells.

Here is a prototype of what I am trying to achieve:
[image]

And here is the snippet:

```
function getBittrexMarketSymbol(sourceCell) {
  // Import current value of the cell and store it here.
  var getCurrentValue; // This bit I don't know how to do.
  getCurrentValue = 0.00123; // For now, we set a dummy value.

  // Query the adjacent cell for the flag
  var range = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveRange();
  var col = range.getColumn();
  var row = range.getRow();
  var range2 = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange(row,col+1);
  var flag = range2.getValue();

  if(typeof sourceCell === 'undefined'){
    // DEBUG Override
    var marketSymbol = 'None';
    Logger.log('No market symbol found: [MARKET_SYMBOL=%s]', marketSymbol)
    return lastprice = -1;
  }

  // Based on a condition we choose to return the live API value
  // or the original value that was already in the cell, prior to execution.
  if(flag===1){
    var marketSymbol = sourceCell;
    var url = "https://api.bittrex.com/v3/markets/"+ marketSymbol +"/ticker";
    var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url);
    var text = response.getContentText();
    var myjson = JSON.parse(text);
    var lastprice = myjson.lastTradeRate;
    return lastprice;
  }else{
    return getCurrentValue; 
  }
}
```

So basically, I would like to run the API call or choose to preserve any existing values on that cell with the pink background.

*Please note that I have to change the cell address to force a re-evaluation of the script.*

Comment: I thought about sweeping all of the column with the API cells, and copy-paste the static values to the column on the left side. So I can simply retrieve the value from there and substitute as an alternative to what comes through the API.

Comment: Your using the tag google-docs, don't you actually mean google-spreadsheet?

Comment: If you need persistent data storage, you can use Properties Service.  The data is permanently saved.  If you only want to store a value for a certain amount of time, then use Cache Service.

Comment: Ok. Thanks. I’m starting to think this is getting too convoluted. It seems it is easier to put a Vue or React app together with a simple backend with a table in there. Moving data across cells, persistent data, I don’t think google-sheets is there yet as in flexible enough to maintain data.

Comment: Can you provide me a snippet of your code, so I can understand what exactly your problem with storing the value is? You can assign it to a const variable and then decide with an if statement either you want to update the value or not. As Alan Wells pointed out, you can also cache the value with Property Service. Or you can copy it to the same cell of a new sheet in the same spreadsheet and then access the value when necessary.

Comment: Sure. Adding a demo gif and a demo script to the question.

Comment: @ziganotschka Hi, I thought I saw your answer here. But then, when I came back it was gone?

Comment: It is still here. https://stackoverflow.com/a/56838398/11599789

Comment: That is really strange, I can't see it. Could you please share it somehow, pastebin or gist. I can't access your solution on stackoverflow.